# Check if ienumerable list is null in where clause

Tags: c#

```
        public static int calcValueMS(FPT doc, int score)
        {
            return doc.PositionSection.ManagedStrategyAssets
                      .Where(a => a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id == score )                                          
                      .SelectMany(h => h.Holdings).Sum(v => v.CurrentValue);
        }
```

My method returns the sum value of some assets. Where they match a risk rating. Sometimes though the risk rating `Id` will be null. I've tried using the ternary operator, but doesn't seem to work.

How can i check if the risk rating Id is null first then see if it is equals to the score?

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly check for that? Is it really the `Id` that is null or the `RiskRating` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RiskRating.Id` seems to be a `int?`, not an `int`, so you can use `HasValue`and `Value`.

You can aggregate many `Where` clauses in your Linq request :

```
public static int calcValueMS(FPT doc, int score)
{
    return doc.PositionSection.ManagedStrategyAssets
              .Where(a => a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id.HasValue)
              .Where(a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id.Value == score)
              .SelectMany(h => h.Holdings)
              .Sum(v => v.CurrentValue);
}
```

Comment: While this post answers the question it should be noted that it adds nothing to the original code since the additional check (`Id.HasValue`) is redundant to `Id == score`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ternary operator just &&-operator:

```
public static int calcValueMS(FPT doc, int score)
{
        return doc.PositionSection.ManagedStrategyAssets
            .Where(a => a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id != null && a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id == score )
            .SelectMany(h => h.Holdings)
            .Sum(v => v.CurrentValue);
}
```

Comment: Since it's most likely a nullable `int`/`long`, you could also do `a.AssetRiskData.RiskMeasure.RiskRating.Id.HasValue` for a little cleaner code.

Comment: The additional checks is not necessary, if `Id` is `null` then the second check (`Id == score`) would return `false` too.